# Why I can't use sinon.useFakeTimers and Meteor._wrapAsync

Tags: meteor, sinon

I try to use `sinon.useFakeTimers` on some tests to make a bunch of `setTimeout` fire and this works fine, except when I call any function that is wrapped with `Meteor._wrapAsync`. I've tried using `Asycn.wrap`, but I had the same result. It doesn't log any error to the console, it just seems to stop (or finalize) execution.

Is there an explanation for this?

I'm using sinon `1.10.3` and meteor `0.8.1.2`.

Comment: Why do you need fakeTimers for a function that is async? You should only ever use faketimers for things like animations that you know use a setTimeout.

Comment: The thing is that there is a function that has a setTimeout inside and later it calls another fn that is wrapped inside `Async.wrap`, and I need to `useFakeTimers` to make the setTimeout fire. I have solved the issue by stubbing the call to the wrapped function, but I would like to know why they don't play well together.

Comment: Good question, have had the same problem myself and just decided not to use fake timers in combination with fibers

Comment: Did you find any alternative to fake timers to simulate the time going forward (to get the setTimeout callbacks fire)?

Comment: think i just made a async test and had it wait till the expected end time of the timeout